# There is no metadata information for provider 'SqlServer-20'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, quartz.net

I want to test the SQL database features of Quartz.NET 3.0 for .NET Core. Unfortunately, I'm unable to configure the `StdSchedulerFactory` properly, I always get the following exception when calling `StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler`:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
There is no metadata information for provider 'SqlServer-20'
Parameter name: providerName
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider.GetDbMetadata(String providerName)
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.Common.DbProvider..ctor(String dbProviderName, String connectionString)
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<Instantiate>d__66.MoveNext()
```

I've configured the factory with the following values:

```cs
var configuration = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "QRTZ_" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default" },
    { "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=QuartzTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" },
    { "quartz.dataSource.default.provider", "SqlServer-20" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true" },
    { "quartz.serializer.type", "json" }
};

var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(configuration);
```

As you can see, I'm currently targeting LocalDB (v12.0.2000). I also checked it on SQL Server Express - same result.

**How can I avoid this exception?**

- Did I miss any properties that I should configure?
- Do I have to provide some data for the database? I only executed the `tables_sqlServer.sql` script.
- The SqlServer-20 database driver should be installed as part of .NET 3.5, or is there a separate installation necessary?
- Does Quartz.NET currently not support this functionality for .NET Core? I'm using version 3.0.0-alpha2.
- Should I target other NuGet packages? I referenced Quartz and Quartz.Serialization.Json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently according to changelog for beta1 there are no versions for providers. So correct provider configuration for SqlServer is:

```
["quartz.dataSource.sqlserver.provider"] = "SqlServer"
```

Source: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e3ff6936ea1a76480b7671e2b5c468c1b67f4897/changelog.md#release-30-beta-1-oct-8-2017

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine just found the answer: according to [this example on Github](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz.Examples/example13/ClusterExample.cs#L98), you have to use `SqlServer-41` instead of `SqlServer-20` in .NET Core projects.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer anymore. I think ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer" is the correct answer. See https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e3ff6936ea1a76480b7671e2b5c468c1b67f4897/src/Quartz.Tests.Unit/TestConstants.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
            NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
            };
            properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=quartznet;Data Source=.\\sqlInstance;";
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";

            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
```